# PHP, AJAX Auto fill input fields from HTML select?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have been trying for a while to find out a correct method of pulling information from a database based on the initial text 
selected on a html drop down menu.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script src="testjs.js"></script>
<?php
    $host = "";
    $username = ""; 
    $password = "";
    $database = "";
    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db($database);
?>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<?php
    $Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM population");
    while ($Rows = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
    {
        $ID = $Rows['ID'];
        $Pop = $Rows['Pop'];
        $UniqueID = $Rows['uid'];
        echo "<option value=\"$UniqueID\">$Pop</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<p>DB ID <input type="text" id="ids" name="ID" ></p>
<p>Population <input type="text" id="content" name="contet" ></p>
<p>Unique ID <input type="text" id="uid" name="uid" ></p>
<div id="GetInformation"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

test.js contains:

```
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("GetInformation").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("GetInformation").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Get user contains:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('', '', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("DropDown", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM population WHERE uid = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $Pop = $row['Pop'];
    $UID = $row['uid'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ids = '<?php echo json_encode($ID); ?>';
var content = '<?php echo json_encode($Pop); ?>';
var uid = '<?php echo json_encode($UID); ?>';
</script>
 <?php }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: What do you really want?

Comment: @thiagoh I think the OP wants to use Javascript to get information from a different table in my database; submit those variables to JavaScript, and using the Javascript display the information contained in the Javascript strings into the `<input type="text">`

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $Pop = $row['Pop'];
    $UID = $row['uid'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ids = '<?php echo json_encode($ID); ?>';
var content = '<?php echo json_encode($Pop); ?>';
var uid = '<?php echo json_encode($UID); ?>';
</script>
 <?php }
```

to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $Pop = $row['Pop'];
    $UID = $row['uid'];
    echo $ID . ' - ' . $Pop . ' - ' . $UID;
}
```

---

this should work. but there are better ways as they give you more access later on in your client side. e.g. send a JSON object back, a quick example would be:

```
$info = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $Pop = $row['Pop'];
    $UID = $row['uid'];

    $info[] = array( 'id' => $ID, 'pop' => $Pop, 'uid' => $UID );
}
echo json_encode($info);
```

and your JS would be something like :

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) 
    {
      document.getElementById("GetInformation").innerHTML += data[i].id + ' - ' + data[i].pop + ' - ' + data[i].uid;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** if you are working with a browser that doesn't include the JSON library you need to load http://www.json.org/js.html . Also your AJAX/DOM changes can become much simpler if you want to use jQuery